# Make the same thing multiple times but with another name

Tags: java, polygon

I want to make the same thing/object  multiple times but al with another name.

Like this: 
I want to make 6 Polygons but each of them with another name:

```
    Polygon p1 = new Polygon();
    Polygon p2 = new Polygon();
    Polygon p3 = new Polygon();
    Polygon p4 = new Polygon();
    Polygon p5 = new Polygon();
    Polygon p6 = new Polygon();
```

Is there a way to do this with a for loop or something else?

Thanks

Comment: An array would make a lot of sense, here.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't solve the problem. What if i want to make 100 polygons?

Comment: @Aleandro: Then you create an array of size 100, and populate it in a loop. It really *does* solve the problem, as you've described it...

Comment: Ok, but I don't understand how you want to do this. Because I want different names. The 99th polygon is named p99. And I don't know how you can do that like you discribe it.

Comment: Why do you want different names? Would `p[1]` and `p[2]` be different names from your point of view?

Comment: I will use it in a graphical game, and every specific polygon has to move to a specific location. So i would like to say  p1.move(....), p2.move(....) , ...

Comment: And what's the problem with `p[1].move(....), p[2].move(....)  ...`?

Comment: Nothing but I want to know if it is possible to do it and give it different names?

Comment: @Aleandro: No that's not possible in Java, as others have already written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't dynamically create variable names in Java.  They need to be available in the source code at compile time.  As others have said, the usual way to do this in Java is to create an array or list.  For example:

```
List<Polygon> polygons = new ArrayList<>();
for (int ctr = 0; ctr < 100; ctr++) {
    polygons.add(new Polygon());
}
```

You reference the object not by a name, but by its *index*.

```
Polygon poly = polygons.get(22);
```

Another way to think about it.  What if you did have 100 individual variable names for your objects.  Then what if you wanted to run some process on all your polygons.  Do you want..

```
doSomething(p1);
doSomething(p2);
// ... lots more lines like this...
doSomething(p99);
```

or simply:

```
for (Polygon poly : polygons) {
    doSomething(poly);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the documentation on [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

In the example code, you would change the name `anArray` to `myPolygons`. And you would need to change the `int` to a `Polygon`. But the idea is the same. You would reference p6 by calling it `myPolygons[6]`. (Or maybe `myPolygons[5]`, because Java is zero-offset, meaning that the first one in your array would be `myPolygons[0]`. And yes, a `for` loop would also help.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should be ok

```
   List<Polygon> polygonObjects = new ArrayList<Polygon>();

    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        polygonObjects.add(new Polygon());
    }
```